# asp.net: Postback disabled after validation failed

Tags: asp.net, validation, postback

After validation failed, I have a problem with controls (dropdownlist or button) that should cause a new postback. I will try to explain it clearly...

The purpose of my page is to save fives dates in a database. The page has the following controls:

- Five textboxes, each one containing a date
- A reset button (CausesValidation=false) to restore a default date in one of the 5 textboxes
- A dropdown list (AutoPostback=true, CausesValidation=false) of predefined templates that applies 5 dates to the 5 textboxes
- A button to save the dates to the database

The textboxes can be edited manually. So, when I click the Save button, if the format of the dates is not valid, the validation fails and the save is aborted. The problem is just after that. If I click on the Reset button or select an item in the dropdownlist, the postback is not triggered. If I try again, then it works. Is there a way to make it work the first time after the first validation failed? I tried deactivating the validation on the client-side when changing the selection in the dropdownlist but the postback still does not occur.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboScheduleTemplates" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateDelivery1" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDateDelivery1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Schedule" ControlToValidate="txtDateDelivery1" Text="*" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateYearbookQuantity" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDateYearbookQuantity" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Schedule" ControlToValidate="txtDateYearbookQuantity" Text="*" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateDelivery2" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDateDelivery2" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Schedule" ControlToValidate="txtDateDelivery2" Text="*" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDatePersonalizations" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDatePersonalizations" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Schedule" ControlToValidate="txtDatePersonalizations" Text="*" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateDelivery3" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSetDefaultDelivery3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Schedule" CausesValidation="false" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDateDelivery3" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Schedule" ControlToValidate="txtDateDelivery3" Text="*" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveSchedule" runat="server" CssClass="btnAction" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="Schedule" />
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="validationSummarySchedule" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Schedule" DisplayMode="List" />
```

Comment: "select an item in the dropdownlist," are you selcting the same item?

Comment: The first item in the dropdownlist is "Choose a template". When a template is selected, the postback should occur. In the server-side code, I set the first item as the selected one again after processing the selection change. So, no, in the scenario that I describe, I do not select the same item.

Comment: Can you post some of the example markup, so we can see how things are set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769597/why-wont-my-form-post-back-after-validation), the problem comes from calls to Page_ClientValidate. So I wrapped the client function like this and the problem went away:

```
function DoPageClientValidate(validationGroupName) 
{
     var result = Page_ClientValidate(validationGroupName);
     Page_BlockSubmit = false;
     return result; 
}
```