# Why does a failed validation prevent postbacks from control in other validation groups?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, postback

I have an asp.net web form with several textboxes, buttons, and other controls. One of the buttons is supposed to trigger validation of content in some of the textboxes. This works fine, except that if validation fails, all subsequent postbacks of the page are prevented. Fixing the invalid values gets rid of the error messages, but postback still does not occur.

The validation is occurring within an AJAX UpdatePanel. I'm not sure if that matters or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm glad [the workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11477963/1637462) is fine for you, but for the benefit of others who land this page, disabling client side validation is far from an acceptable solution. So here goes:

Why it happened only when `UpdatePanel` was around, is still unclear to me, however:

As others have mentioned, the issue you were having is most likely because the unsuccessful validation attempt is preventing a further postback.

See also: [Why won't my form post back after validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769597/why-wont-my-form-post-back-after-validation)

There is a variable called `Page_BlockSubmit` which is set to true when client side validation fails:

```
function Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup) {
    ....
    Page_BlockSubmit = !Page_IsValid;
    return Page_IsValid;
}
```

So when a `__doPostBack` occurs as part of, say, an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` of a `DropDownList`, there is this check:

```
function ValidatorCommonOnSubmit() {
    ....
    var result = !Page_BlockSubmit; /* read the value */
    ....
    Page_BlockSubmit = false; /* reset it */
    return result; 
}
```

Which will block the first time, but then clear the flag, so the next postback attempt should work.

The workaround, in my case, for a `DropDownList`'s `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, was to have a snippet added to its client-side `onchange` event:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="SomeDropDownList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AlwaysDoSomething"
   onchange="resetValidationState(this);">
    ....
</asp:DropDownList>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetValidationState() {
        // clear any postback blocks, which occur after validation fails:
        window.Page_BlockSubmit = false;
    }
</script>
```

You might get away with putting that snippet into the `onchange` itself.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to fix my issue today, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> except that after this button has been clicked no other button can cause a postback unless the validation errors have been corrected. So, btnDelete, which should not require validation of the textboxes, cannot postback until the textbox values are corrected

Don't see that behavior with following code..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="pc">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit"  Width="150" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="pc" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" CausesValidation="false"  />
```

Comment: sorry that my initial description was not comprehensive. I don't want to post all my markup or code behind because it is quite large. I've updated my question based on a little more troubleshooting I've been doing. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Even with updatepanel i don't see that behavior..make sure there are no JS errors on the page after validation failure

Comment: Nope; no script errors. I guess something else on the page must be messing with the validation/postback scripts? Let's see if I can figure out what...

Comment: It definitely has something to do with the UpdatePanel. I just commented out the UpdatePanel and everything works as expected (except with full postbacks rather than async postbacks).

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally off base here - but i think I see the problem. (I work mainly with devexpress controls so the rules can be a bit different). When validation fails, the whole page is set to invalid, so no postbacks can occur. Can it be since the delete button is not causing any validation, its not re validating after those editors have been changed to be valid?